# How to show "Previous Category" and "Next Category" in categories archieve template

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories

I want to show Previous category and Next category links in a category archive page in woocommerce template.  I got this code from another post but for me errors are coming. These are the errors,

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted
>   to string in [FILE] and undefined variable for $next_cat and $prev_cat

```
$this_category = get_queried_object();
$categories = get_categories();

foreach( $categories as $position => $cat ) :
if( $this_category->term_id == $cat->term_id ) :
    $next_cat = $position + 1;
    $prev_cat = $position - 1;
    break;
endif;
endforeach;

$next_cat = $next_cat == count($categories) ? 0 : $next_cat;
$prev_cat = $prev_cat < 0 ? count($categories) - 1 : $prev_cat;

echo 'previous: ' . get_term_link( $categories[$prev_cat] );
echo 'next: ' . get_term_link( $categories[$next_cat] );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is impossibke to remoteky debug things you should investigate and fix the errors you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about PHP, not about WordPress, but here you go: [`get_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) returns a simple array of categories, not an indexed array. Your `foreach` loop tries to adress it as an indexed array. Hence the error. Also, `$position` becomes an undefined variable, and the loop is unnecessary anyway.

```
$position = array_search ($this_category->term_id, $categories);
$next_cat = $position + 1;
$prev_cat = $position - 1;
```

Please make sure `get_categories` is returning an array of ID's and not something else.

Comment: Yes, This suggestion deleted errors and i am getting links also, but I am getting same category link for both Next and previous links (i.e present category link)

Comment: you could debug this by echoing intermediate results: $position, $next_cat, $categories[$next_cat]. This will tell you where things go wrong.

Comment: That helped, Many Thanx